# localhost/phpmyadmin not working, just see a bunch of text

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: localhost phpmyadmin not working]

I'm trying to get phpMyAdmin to work, but it seems like it's proving to be a lot more difficult than I thought it would be.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

BTW I'm using PHP 7 on GalliumOS (basically Ubuntu for Chromebooks).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: What process did you used during your LAMP installation? Your Ubuntu and Chromebook version? Any error in your *`var/log/apache2/error.log`*?

Comment: IDK I just kinda looked up tutorials online... Sorry I can't be more clear, but I'm kind of a noob and I really don't remember which exact ones I used. For the record, `localhost` itself works. I guess the problem might be with my phpmyadmin installation, then. I'll try reinstalling.

Comment: Run `sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php`, then type in `<?php
phpinfo();`. Save and close the file with Ctrl-X; you will be prompted to confirm by typing Y and then hit Enter to complete the process. You may then visit `http://your_server_IP_address/info.php`. What do you see?

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it. I did what you said and it says 404 not found.

Comment: If I type in `localhost/info.php` it shows `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: That's a strange result; you should check the location of the file (info.php): you must have gotten it absolutely wrong.

Comment: Hmm did you see my other comment? I might have just used the wrong ip address... I was using my public ip adress but I guess that might be different from my server ip address?

Comment: Also for the record this works: http://i.imgur.com/aGD07w7.png

Comment: Here's an image of what I see with localhost: http://i.imgur.com/ExWrN4j.png

Comment: Hey @nyedidikeke just wanted to let you know that it somehow works now! Thanks for all your help. It wasn't even working earlier this morning but I just randomly tried it again and now it works. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but I stumbled into the same problem, and

```
sudo a2enmod php7.x
```

(php 7.x is the actual php version) 
fixed my issue (apparently php was updated and the new version was not enabled in apache)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you already have PHP installed, you may resolve it by editing your **`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`**, adding the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

*Remember to restart Apache after saving your changes.*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I typed in:
`sudo service apache2 stop` and then
`sudo service apache2 start` into my terminal and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have PHP installed? Run `php -v` to check.

Comment: Yup! PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`, then, locate `<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>` and change the current order to `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm`. After this, save and close the file by pressing Ctrl-X; you'll have to confirm the save by typing Y and then hit Enter to confirm so as to save the changes. Restart Apache by running `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.

Comment: Thanks nyedidikeke, I really appreciate the help, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Thank you very much. I just add this on my `apache2.conf` working on php7.2 and solve my issue. Working very well on 2019